# Is there an efficient way to decompress bytearrays (gzip) to String?

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, gzip, compression

I'm trying to decompress a larg bytearray with around 1,500,000 bytes.

The data is retrieved from a webservice as a bas64 string which i decode first to bytearray.

The bytearray consists of a compressed JSON string which I wan't to read an object model from via GSON.

My App is using around ~12MB RAM before i start my decompression method below:

```
public static String decompress(byte[] arr) {
        if(arr == null || arr.length == 0)
            return null;

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(arr.length);
            GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(arr));
            int len;
            while ((len = gzip.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0 ,len);
            }
            gzip.close();
            out.close();
            System.gc();
            return out.toString("UTF-8");

        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

While writing to the output stream the OOM Exception occures.

I already checked many SO questions but the only hint I got was that coding it as a streaming process would help but this wasen't explaint at all and I dind't find any leads on the net. **So if somebody knows if it is possible to do the decompression memory efficent please expain it or link an article that covers the topic.**

Comment: Do not use strings for binary data!

Comment: Everything works fine unless the array is to big so please consider giving a solution instead. Also a "do not use X" isn't helpful unless you explain why.

Comment: Well, do you think a string is accurate to represent binary data? One thing it "does" for you is basically nearly double your input size, for one. Just return a byte array. IOW: just `return out.toByteArray();`

Comment: OK, let's take the problem another way; why do you return an in memory representation? Can't you store that in a file and read from that file later instead?

Comment: I'm retrieving a webservice that sends a base64 encoded string. I decode that to a byte array. The data inside is a gziped json string which i want to parse via GSON to the respective classes.

Comment: Aah, now we're talking. That is a precise definition of the problem and you should edit your question to reflect that. But you still have a problem. If all your POJOs need to be in memory at once, you'll reach an OOM either way. If you can afford to have "only a few" POJOs in memory at the time, then use GSON's streaming API.

Comment: btw, if you control the server there are easier ways to do this. Just have a regular json output with an http compress header. your webclient will automatically decompress the stream and you can pass that into gson (or jackson which is better for streaming) seamlessly

Comment: I have to look into that I'll try to put the JSON in a file first and then if there is a OOM Exception while streaming from JSON I just have to splitt the content in smaller pieces. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Okay I decompressed the bytearray directly to a file and read the string from this file. I can even directly use GSONs fromJson method.  Thank you again :)